# Visual Studio thinks Obj.Equals(Obj) isn't always true. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was writing the test case for my code and noticed something unusual about Visual studio. Generally VS indicates the unreachable code but in below code it did not.

```
Object a = 5;
if(a.Equals(a))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
}
```

Is it ever possible that we will fall in else case or it's something visual studio didn't catch?

If so how can we can do it, any examples?

Comment: `public override bool Equals(object obj) { return false; }`

Comment: Depends on the implementation of Equals on the object

Comment: Well, resharper suggests this: `Console.WriteLine("Equal");` :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter ?

Comment: @RandRandom: resharper suggests to replace the whole `if...else` branches with `Console.WriteLine("Equal");` because that is what will always happen.

Comment: Right. You can not override Equals on the Object type itself, neither can you do an extension method. As long as you assign a constant value like your hardcoded ``5``, this will always be true. If you assign an instance of any object that is ``Equatable``, you depend on the implementation of that Equals method and then in theory it could return false if equals contains strange code like ``return o == 2`` or something.
But in your example on a plain object, using a fix assigned (boxed) integer of ``5`` I see no way to modify the Equals implementation. So it is always true I think.

Comment: @Dennis_E So do think it's just VS implementation flaw and there nothing more. I am asking this because i know some java and when tried same code in java Eclipse also did indicate unreachable code

Comment: In this example, there is no way `a.Equals(a)` will give false. I guess the compiler doesn't feel it's necessary to analyze `a.Equals(a)`. If you say `if(true)`, it *will* give a warning for unreachable code.

Comment: _"when tried same code in java Eclipse"_ That's comparing oranges and apples.

Comment: @Fildor I thought the same but when two IDE showed the same thing then i though i might be missing something (internals of this implementation)

Comment: Then you should have compared NetBeans, IntelliJ and Eclipse ... But VS vs Eclipse / Java vs C# tells you nothing. Equals could have completely different contracts and therefore result in different warnings (outside other reasons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx:

> x.Equals(x) returns true, except in cases that involve floating-point types. See ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559:2011, Information technology -- Microprocessor Systems -- Floating-Point arithmetic.

Comment: Interesting but i dont understand it. If i use a `double` it works, even with `double.NaN`(which returns `false` if you use `double.NaN==double.NaN`).

Comment: Its because floating point numbers are represented to a very high precision in binary. Because of this, numbers that appear to be the same could be slightly different.

Comment: @MirtHlaj I'm not sure that floating point precision *alone* accounts for *the same instance* not comparing with its self.  Surely the same value, stored in the same instance, in the same variable will always have the same bit-wise representation of its self?  There ISO document referenced by MSDN is, unfortunately, unavailable without payment.